# Need to Check Username

Tags: javascript, csom

In the "Created By"List Column I need to search if Current login user is present or not using Java Script. How can I achieve that.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more on what you want to achieve? SharePoint without JavaScript does not do much. It won't display Views so ``created by`` is never displayed/processed front-end side.

Comment: I have list where I need to update list items based on logged in user. So First I need to check who is logged in user (I did) now I want to check if that user name presents in that Particular List's created By column.so that I can take the Item Id and update the value.

Comment: Where do you want to execute this code? In the List View?

Comment: You need to check it for all items or a particular item?

Comment: Need to check the items for a particular item i.e. created by

Comment: then see my answer, any confusion?

Answer (score 2):

So you need to check if

```
Created By == Current User
```

You can find current user by following line of code

```
var currentUserId = _spPageContextInfo.userId
```

Now filter items based on `currentUserId`. You have to make a GET request in the following `URL`

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('List Name')/Items?$filter=AuthorId eq currentUserId
```

Full code should look like following

```
    function currentUsersItems(listName, currentUserId) {
    var url = "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('" + listName + "')/Items?$filter=AuthorId eq " + currentUserId + "";
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + url,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function(data) {
            var currentUsersItems = data.d.results;
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: He wants it for all items. So I think it should be /items?$filter=AuthorId eq <userID>.

Comment: Thanks @Akhoy. His question and comments messed me up. I am giving a update

Answer (score 2):

Provided you are executing this **in a VIEW with the Created By column displayed** all information is available in the `ctx` object and `_spPageContextInfo` and you do not need any round-trips back to the server

*proof of concept code, run from Dev Console*

```
ctx.ListData.Row.forEach(function(row){
   console.log(row);
   var user=row.Author[0];
   if(user.id===_spPageContextInfo.userId){ 
       console.info('match',user.title,'item ID',row.ID)
   };
});
```

You can use CSR or other coding techniques to process *per* ListItem

PS. I presume you know you can filter a View on the Current User with: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Its a 2 step work.

**First is to get the current logged in user and store it in variable**

```
// Getting current user
//
var currentUser = null;
function getCurrentUser() {
    try {
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var tempcurrentUser = clientContext.get_web().get_currentUser();
        clientContext.load(tempcurrentUser); 
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
            var index = tempcurrentUser.get_loginName().indexOf('|') + 1;
            currentUser = tempcurrentUser.get_loginName().substring(index);

        }, 
        function () {
            alert("Error");
        });
    }
    catch (err) {
        alert("Error");
    }
}
```

**Second** is to query SharePoint List with item Id and check if the current user is the one in `created by` field value.

```
//Get the list item whose Id is 4. Note that this is the ID of the item in the list, not a reference to its position in the collection.
var itemId = 4;   
var targetListItem;

function runCode() {
  var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(); 
  var targetList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('YourListName');
  targetListItem = targetList.getItemById(itemId);
  clientContext.load(targetListItem, 'Author');
  clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {

    if(currentUser == targetListItem.get_item('Author') {
        // Its checked that current user is the creator of this item
        // Here you write code to update your item
    }

}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
  alert('Request failed. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: But here I need to iterate every author name in the list to match with the login user name ...

Comment: You can use `caml` query where `createdby=currentUser`. With the help of this query you will get all items whose author is current user example you get 5 items. Then you update those 5 items.